# No charge inside a conductor

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

So we say that charge on a conductor resides on the surface, so why is that so, and I heard some explanation saying that because electric field inside the conductor is zero. But why is that so?

Comment: Do electrons want to stay close together or far apart?

Comment: Far apart , but even if they are at the surface wouldn't they be together there , because if they are uniformly distributed over volume wouldn't they be more far apart?

Comment: Think about a square room with 10 people in it. If everyone thought the others were infected with a contagious desease, they would not stand uniformly in the room to stay away from the others, they would all run to the walls and spread evenly around the perimeter of the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conductor is any material where charges can move, and they are characterized by their conductivity, usually denoted $\sigma$. Within a conductor, the current density is given by $\mathbf{J}=\sigma\mathbf{E}$: the current density is the conductivity times the electric field.

This gives an important concept - and the same concept applies to a plasma - if there *was* an electric field inside a conductor, current would move to eliminate that electric field. If there was an electric field in the $\hat{x}$ direction, it would make a current in the $\hat{x}$ direction, moving electrons in the $-\hat{x}$ directions. This would make an excess of electrons on the left, which make an electric field in the $-\hat{x}$ direction. This proceeds until the electric field is gone.

So there's no electric field in a conductor. That means the voltage is constant everywhere in the conductor. Taking the laplacian we can find the charge density inside the conductor is zero:
$$
V(x,y,z)=\text{const}
$$
$$
\nabla^2 V(x,y,z)=\frac{\rho(x,y,z)}{\epsilon_0}=0
$$

But what about the surface? There is no electric field inside the conductor, but there totally can be an electric field pointing outward from the conductor on the surface. If you pass through a surface charge density $s$, we have a change in the electric field of $s/\epsilon_0$. So any free charge in a conductor sits on the surface, and it creates an electric field perpendicular to the surface of magnitude $s/\epsilon_0$. It has to be perpendicular because otherwise different points along the surface of the conductor would be different voltages. This charge also moves around to ensure that the surface of the conductor remains an equipotential. If you try to apply an electric field to a spherical conductor, some charge will move to cancel out that electric field inside the conductor.

Comment: Ohh okay got it. Thanks